# How to apply mouseover function to component in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have the following elements:

**Parent.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte';

    function handleMouse(){

    }

</script>

<Child on:mousedown={handleMouseDown} on:mouseover={handleMouse}/>

<div draggable="true" on:mousedown={handleMouseDown} on:mouseover={handleMouse}>Text</div>
```

**Child.svelte**

```
<div draggable="true">Child text</div>
```

How can I get the `handleMouse()` function to work on the child component, when the function is in the parent component?

I can recreate the function inside of the child component, but is there a way to just bind to the parent functions for the child element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forward events from a child component by specifying `on:` with only the event name, e.g.

```html
<div draggable="true" on:mousedown on:mouseover >Child text</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to forward *to* a child component, not *from*

Comment: That is what this does, you have to forward the event from the child to the parent, so it can be handled there.